# Deploying applications that use LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to use L2E since it's very convenient to my company's apps, I created a demo project, the demo does run on every machine but when I, let's say, press a button that has some code that uses the entity I get this error:

```
specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.
```

note that I get this error only on machines that does not have VS2008 installed, on these machines (the ones with VS2008) the demo works well. any advice is appreciated.

I am using MySql server with Mysql Conector 6.3 and the model is created with ADO.Net entitiy model.

**EDIT**

here is the complete error trace:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
   at Projects.projectsEntities..ctor()
   at Projects.frmProjecstMain.btnGenerarProyectoDeGarantias_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3603 (GDR.050727-3600)
    CodeBase: file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Projects
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/jessica.carreon/Local%20Settings/Apps/2.0/1MLH514G.07M/RGBATG69.8AR/proj..tion_b0cb148e1dc400e0_0001.0000_738d35d08c548573/Projects.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
MySql.Data
    Assembly Version: 6.3.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.3.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/jessica.carreon/Local%20Settings/Apps/2.0/1MLH514G.07M/RGBATG69.8AR/proj..tion_b0cb148e1dc400e0_0001.0000_738d35d08c548573/MySql.Data.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.Entity
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.1 built by: SP
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.Entity/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.Entity.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.1 built by: SP
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: Also add the config file sections that are related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your app.config file the entity model connection has to point to the right server, the server must be accessible (i.e. your security settings have to be correct and your network set up right). We need more information about your environment. Right now I can only assume you don't know how to connect to a server from your Windows application.

Update:  Does this solve your problem?  http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13286

Comment: I am doing this to MySql, all my projects currently use datasets, the server is visible and security settings ar OK.

Comment: Are there any compiler warnings or errors (and yet it completes compilation) at all when you build, or during design time of your entity model?  This is just to exclude one possibility.

Comment: I'm thinking on your dev boxes you have the MySQL assemblies registered in the GAC or otherwise easily found by the CLR, but on your other machines you'll have to ensure those assemblies are loaded correctly. You configuration file must have some section that is pointing to an assembly that it cannot find. Did you try stepping through the code with Debug - Exceptions - CLR Exceptions Thrown checked? Then see if there's an internal file not found exception or something like that.

Comment: Note that often in app.config files when something is incorrect, i.e. a public key token or whatever, it will end up saying the configuration is invalid, but not bubble up the file not found exception.

Comment: Also, if you debug on the machine where it works, break right where the exception would be thrown, and check Debug - Windows - Modules and check the paths/versions/tokens on all the MySql related dlls.  Make sure they exist in corresponding locations on the machines you are deploying too.

Comment: It also may be as simple as setting Copy Local = true for CoreLab.MySql.Entity.dll, like the guy ends up doing in the link I provided.

Comment: I am not using corelab, I am using ADO

Comment: Same principle, same problem.  Instead of Corelab.MySql.Entity.dll, look for MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity.dll, in the stack trace in your question, there is only MySql.Data, and it's in your LocalSettings folder.  It's not deployed properly.  Set copy local = true for both those assemblies in your project.  If that doesn't work then there must be an installation required for the provider (which will probably put it in the GAC).

Comment: do you think that installing the connector on user machines will solve this?

Comment: Most definitely, but you may not have to install it, you might just have to use copy local = true and ensure they are deployed (i.e. if you have a setup project, make sure those MySql dlls get in there and target the GAC installation folder).  If it's faster for you to install the connector, try that, and at least you'll know that the dlls are missing/in the wrong place etc....

Comment: nope, maybe I need to add the provider to the app.config, can you help me out with this? the dlls are deploying correctly.

Comment: Your app.config is completely missing everything to do with the provider ... check the app.config you have in your project, it must be different.  I am not familiar with all the specific sections.  Your deployed app.config file must be totally different than your project app.config.

Comment: Try this but make sure the key token/version etc... is correct, I am just copying this from some place else .... <system.data> <DbProviderFactories> <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /> </DbProviderFactories> </system.data>

Comment: thanks, I tried this but maybe I missed something, I just copied it, put the version and token... it works... I love you... not really.. still you deserve half my rep...

Answer (score 1):

I had to install Mysql Connector on the target machine, there didn't seem to be any way around it. perhaps it registers assemblies in the GAC

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience as Markus.  I had to resort to installing the MySQL Connector on the production machine to get things to work.  It worked fine.  Same configuration file.

Before resorting to installing the MySQL Connector I tried adding to the bin: MySql.Data.dll, 
MySql.Data.Entity.dll, MySql.Web.dll, System.Data.Entity.dll. That didn't work for me.

My configuration prodution machine: MySQL Connector Net 6.3.7 and using .NET 4.0 framework
My dev machine: MySQL Connector Net 6.3.7 and using .NET 4.0 framework, Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework uses a custom formatted connection string, so you have to ensure it points to the correct database.  The machines also have .NET 3.5 SP 1 installed too, right?

What kind of database are you targeting?

Comment: I am doing this to MySql, all my projects currently use datasets, the server is visible and security settings ar OK.

Answer (score 0):

install mysql-connector-net-6.4.3 or higer on your target machine