# EntityFramework,The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

I have a Winform application and am using EntityFramework. The application runs just fine in my dev machine but when I try to run at client's machine I get "The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid" error. I have distributed EntityFramework.dll with the client. Why am I getting this error? I am not putting the connection strings in the app.config file as it is dynamically created based on the database selected at runtime.(I am using VistaDB as database)

The app.config is below:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection,EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
 </connectionStrings>
 <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705108/mysql-entity-framework-error-the-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found-in-t

Comment: This really looks like a wrong connectionString issue. Specifically check the Data Source part of the string and that it really corresponds to a valid database.

Comment: @Alkaline I haven't put any connectionstring in the app.config file. It is dynamically added at runtime. Moreover the application works fine in my dev machine; the error shows up only in the client machine

Comment: @easternwind: I did get that. The connection string is different between dev and client machines. I'd triple check that the connection string used on the client machine is valid for the db used by the client machine. You can use SQL Server Tools to verify the Data Source that should be used for the client for instance.

Comment: @jeff  i have the same problem bro

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596850/oracle-and-entity-framework-errorthe-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. I uninstalled Connector .NET and reinstalled it. Now it works.

Comment: This worked for me too. I have to reinstall this 1-2 times each month to make it keep working, makes no sense...

Comment: what do you mean of " Connector .NET", where did you uninstall(on the second machine)?

Answer (score 0):

based on which type of DataBase you use you need to provide Db ORM settings that is going to used by Entityframe work

```
 <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory,MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation along with the correct code, people are here to learn as well as fix their issue. The "Why" is as important as the "How" here on SO.

Comment: based on which type of DataBase you use you need to provide Db ORM settings that is going to used by Entityframe work.

Comment: Edit the answer, do not leave additional information in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this error, install [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) on your client's computer.